# How to make my graphs automatically update

Tags: floats, graphs

I use matlab for my graphs and put them in as figures.
How can I make it so the graphs update when recompiled, after I change them in matlab.

Comment: Hi Eirikur, welcome to the Forum!
I assume you include the figures as PNG or the like? If so you would have to export the figures from MATLAB again and recompile your TeX-document. You could also write a MATLAB-script that starts the export and recompile-process!

Comment: Hi @eirikur bernhardsson and welcome to TeX-SE. In `Matlab` you may use `saveas` and `print` commands. You should save figures direct where your `.tex` will look for figures. I suggest to export in `.eps`, mainly using `eps2c`. Compiling LaTeX is independent from Matlab. You may write a script to compile `latex` from `Matlab`. I also developed some functions to write repetitive syntax creating `latex` files directly from `Matlab`. Check my [Matlab to LaTeX library](https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/72155-matlab-to-latex-library) at FileExchange.

Comment: The images of a latex document are not embedded in any way in the source document as in word processors, but just linked by the code  `\includegraphics{\path\filename}`.  While the updated image is still in the same path with the same name, you only have to recompile.